# How to use common entity in more than one entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have one entity `Address` and  this entity is owned by two other entities.

Ex

`@JoinColumn` and `mappedBy` use foreign key either for `User` or  `Company`. 
How to fix this problem to work address for both user and company?

I've tried `@JoinColumn` and `mappedBy`, but no luck.

```
@Entity
class User {
    ...
    @OneToMany
    private List<Address> address;
    ...
}

@Entity
class Company{
    ...
    @OneToMany 
    private List<Address> address;
    ...
}

@Entity
class Address {
    private String street;
    private String city;
    private String state;

    private String entityType; // User or Company
    private String entityId; // id of User or Company 
}
```

Comment: does the address really need to refer back to the entity it belongs to? or should it be a one-way relation? should the address be an entity at all or should it be an embedded class?

Answer (score 0):

one-If you're not stuck with a database schema requiring owner type and id in address,  then you should consider a "join" table.   You can annotate for Hibernate using @JoinTable, as follows:

```
@Entity
class Company {
    ...
    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable( name="company_address", 
       joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="idCompany")},
       inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="idAddress"} )
    List<Address> addresses;    
}
```

You need to add the company_address table (and another one for user_address), which will have idCompany and idAddress foreign key columns.  Hibernate will do the rest.

Among other things, doing a one-to-many with a join table like this also allows more than one entity (users, company's etc) to refer to the *same* address, which would not be possible if Address has a single owner.